# WooCommerce REST API Create Product with Categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the WooCommerce REST API V3 legacy. I can use their latest API, if necesssary

I am trying to create a product with categories, but the product has none. What is wrong with my request?

```
POST https://XX.com/taiyi/wc-api/v3/products?consumer_key=XX&consumer_secret=XXHTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic XX
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: XX.com
Content-Length: 228
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"product":{"managing_stock":true,"title":"Testing123-1","sku":"Testing123-3","price":0.0,"categories":[{"id":"254","name":"10 needles with tube Bulk Pack","slug":"10-needles-with-tube-bulk-pack"}],"stock_quantity":0,"tags":[]}}
```

Response

```
{"product":{"title":"Testing123-1","id":3673,"created_at":"2017-06-08T17:20:05Z","updated_at":"2017-06-08T17:20:05Z","type":"simple","status":"publish","downloadable":false,"virtual":false,"permalink":"https:\/\/amplusclient.com\/taiyi\/product\/testing123-1-3\/","sku":"Testing123-3","price":"","regular_price":"","sale_price":null,"price_html":"<br>","taxable":true,"tax_status":"taxable","tax_class":"","managing_stock":true,"stock_quantity":0,"in_stock":false,"backorders_allowed":false,"backordered":false,"sold_individually":false,"purchaseable":false,"featured":false,"visible":true,"catalog_visibility":"visible","on_sale":false,"product_url":"","button_text":"","weight":null,"dimensions":{"length":"","width":"","height":"","unit":"cm"},"shipping_required":true,"shipping_taxable":true,"shipping_class":"","shipping_class_id":null,"description":"","short_description":"","reviews_allowed":true,"average_rating":"0.00","rating_count":0,"related_ids":[],"upsell_ids":[],"cross_sell_ids":[],"parent_id":0,"categories":[],"tags":[],"images":[{"id":0,"created_at":"2017-06-08T17:20:06Z","updated_at":"2017-06-08T17:20:06Z","src":"https:\/\/amplusclient.com\/taiyi\/wp-content\/plugins\/woocommerce\/assets\/images\/placeholder.png","title":"Placeholder","alt":"Placeholder","position":0}],"featured_src":false,"attributes":[],"downloads":[],"download_limit":-1,"download_expiry":-1,"download_type":"standard","purchase_note":"","total_sales":0,"variations":[],"parent":[],"grouped_products":[],"menu_order":0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your request would work if you were using the latest version of the API. In the latest version the [documentation](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product) you can see that your categories object matches theirs. The legacy v3 is a bit different though.

#### WooCommerce REST API  v3 Legacy:

The documentation indicates that you pass the category id's in as a list of integers. It looks like you were trying to include an object with name, slug, and id. I've edited your request below to meet the v3 spec.

```
 {
    "product":
    {
        "managing_stock":true,
        "title":"Testing123-1",
        "sku":"Testing123-3",
        "price":0.0,
        "categories":[254],
        "stock_quantity":0,
        "tags":[]
    }
 }
```

[Reference](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v3.html#create-a-product)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution. Can you tell me how to achieve same for tag? I am sending tags id in array like categories but tags are not being saved. 
"categories":[160],
"tags":[150],